# Laravel Chumper/Zipper Permission Denied while extracting

Tags: php, laravel, zip

I just installed `Chumper/Zipper` to extract `zip` files which will be uploaded. After upload I want to extract the file.

So I tried this way:

`\Zipper::make(storage_path($path . $zip_file))->extractTo($path);`

So `$path` is a folder in my `storage` folder and the `$zip_file` is the name of the uploaded file.

If I try to upload now (upload works etc.) im getting the following error message:

`mkdir(): Permission denied`

I gave the whole laravel project the ownership of non-root user.
Also the `$path` folder in storage has `0755` rights.